# Forcing rerender in WPF 4.0

Tags: wpf, behavior, repaint

I'm trying to use this code to force my progress view to paint before processing begins:

```
public static class ProgressBehaviors
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ForceRepaintProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "ForceRepaint",
        typeof(bool),
        typeof(ProgressBehaviors),
        new UIPropertyMetadata(false, OnForceRepaintChanged));

    public static bool GetForceRepaint(FrameworkElement treeViewItem)
    {
        return (bool)treeViewItem.GetValue(ForceRepaintProperty);
    }

    public static void SetForceRepaint(FrameworkElement treeViewItem, bool value)
    {
        treeViewItem.SetValue(ForceRepaintProperty, value);
    }

    static void OnForceRepaintChanged(DependencyObject a_object, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Border item = a_object as Border;
        if (item == null)
            return;

        item.IsVisibleChanged += (s, ev) =>
            {
                item.UpdateLayout();
                Window window = Window.GetWindow(item);
                if (window != null)
                    window.Measure(window.RenderSize);
            };
    }
}
```

Basic behavior injection.  The reason i have to do this is because otherwise the please wait progress message is not shown until after its done doing whatever it has to do. I'm trying `UpdateLayout` and `Measure` and neither works. Everybody tells me that I'm doing things wrong in WPF.  What, am I supposed to wrap every process I'm doing in a second thread or a Dispatcher invoke?  That seems ugly.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't do heavy processing on the UI thread and at the same time have a responsive UI since the UI thread will be busy. You can have a dedicated UI thread for each `Window` though, so in theory I think you could create a new "Please Wait"-`Window` with `WindowStyle="None"` etc. with its own dedicated UI thread.I've never tried it though. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkpropertymetadata.affectsrender.aspx

Comment: @Meleak, I just want the progress to show as simply as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way: http://dedjo.blogspot.com/2007/08/how-to-doevents-in-wpf.html